# Overheating of GPU using CSS3 animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gif

I'm developing my own website and so I built-in two simple CSS animations which move two png files up and down.

Is it possible that they overheat the GPU? If so, how can I solve this issue?

I would like to use a gif file but if I use JS to animate it will affect the CPU, right?

Comment: No, it's definitely not CSS animation :)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to make a modern GPU be overheated by only some CSS animation ;) If you were talking of big 3D animations, rendering thousands of objects in an extreme resolution, maybe it would be possible.